# How do I setup BIND9 and VirtualBox so that my local machine can access my domain names?

Tags: 13.04, networking, server, virtualbox, dns

I have a complicated setup. And it makes me a bit confused about how I should setup my server, BIND9, and my Mac OS X.

So here it is. I have a Mac that is connected to the internet via WiFi. I have Ubuntu installed on my external hard drive that is connected via USB to my MacBook. I am able to run it via VirtualBox. I control it via ssh in my terminal. So I am running Ubuntu Server v.13 (64Bit). On my Ubuntu Server I have NGiNX running, and BIND9.

When I access the IP via the browser everything works and I connect to my server. I even tried ping and everything is OK.

Here is what I have tried in the BIND9 configs:

*named.conf.local:*

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "exemple.com.jn" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.exemple.com.jn";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.192";
};
```

I added this file: *db.exemple.com.jn*

```
;
; BIND data file for example.com
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     exemple.com.jn. root.exemple.com.jn. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
        IN      A       192.168.1.111
;
@       IN      NS      ns.exemple.com.jn.
@       IN      A       192.168.1.111
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
ns      IN      A       192.168.1.111
```

*db.192*

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.exemple.com.jn. root.exemple.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.
1.0.0   IN      PTR     ns.exemple.com.jn.
```

Here is the error I got: Oops! Google Chrome could not find
When I ping I get this: ping: unknown host

I tried to follow the instructions from: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns-configuration.html

I imagine they are other things I need to modify, but I am unsure what they are. Also do I need to to modify something on my Mac so that it can connect or see the DNS server on my Ubuntu Server so that I can eccess exemple.com.jn.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add your Mac in the zone ,and in the mac you should specify the ubuntu

server is the primary Dns .

Ubuntu server should be connected to the Internet , and edit /etc/bind/named.conf.options

and state your isp dns server .

In Mac just state the ip of Ubuntu server as Dns

Comment: First how do I do I point my Mac to my DNS server?

Comment: first , can you ping your ubuntu from mac ?

Comment: I said in my question that I was able to access the IP from the Browser of my Mac. I was also able to ping it.